# Is energy transferred between parts of a spinning disk moving relative to an observer?

Tags: thermodynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum

I had been thinking about rotating objects and in particular frames of reference.
What I had thought of is that if some sort of rotating disk were to be moving in a linear fashion relative to you (who are stationary), in specific moving at the speed of the disk at its outermost edge, then at one side of the disk there would be a place in which the motion would be zero, and on the other side a place in which the speed would be double that if it was stationary to you.
That is to say that if you track a portion of the disk as it rotates it would be accelerating, decelerating, and repeating.
I would imagine this means that energy is being exchanged actively, so would this energy not become dissonant in some way (heat), perhaps in my ignorance, it seems to me as though there's a sort of violation of thermodynamics taking place.

Please inform me, thank you.

Comment: *"in specific moving at the speed of the disk at its outermost edge, then at one side of the disk there would be a place in which the motion would be zero, and on the other side a place in which the speed would be double that if it was stationary to you."* Well, only in a specific reference frame.

Comment: *"I would imagine this means that energy is being exchanged actively, so would this energy not become dissonant in some way (heat)"* why do you think this energy transfer must be driven from a temperature difference?

Comment: well, I thought it was similar to a perpetual motion machine, doing work without an energy source, and with them being impossible I assumed that the reasoning would be similar.

Answer (score 1):

A rotating disk is a specific instance of something that in in general can be described as a 'bound system'.

The disk has a structural integrity. When spinning the material is put under tension, so as to provide required centripetal force to keep the disk together.

All of the mass of the disk is in a state of acceleration, towards the axis of rotation.

The bound system does not have to be a solid object. Another example would be a set of objects, connected by flexible wires to a central hub. When spinning the tension force in the flexible wires provides required centripetal force.

It is clear there is no force component in a direction perpendicular to the radial direction. If such a force component would be there then the flexible wires would bend, and they dont't bend.

So there is no transfer of velocity component in the direction perpendicular to radial.

Now let's look at the case of a wheel rolling over a surface. Of course, the point where the wheel is in contact with the ground has no velocity relative to the ground. On the opposite side of the wheel, the section opposite to the contact patch section, the velocity relative to the ground is twice the velocity of the wheel-as-a-whole relative to the ground.

So your question is:
Does it make sense to regard each part of the wheel as constantly being accelerated and decelerated relative to the road?

Think of the rotation of every part of the wheel decomposed in a component parallel to the velocity of the road, and a component perpendicular to the velcoity of the road.

These two acceleration components are provided by the corresponding force components.

Then there is the matter of attribution of kinetic energy.

Relative to the road the attribution of kinetic energy shifts. But that is not actual gain or loss of kinetic energy.

The thing is:
While there is relativity of *inertial motion*, accelerated motion is *not* relative.

The spinning wheel, by virtue of its spinning motion, acts as a reference of motion.

This is related to the fact that a spinning wheel acts as a *gyroscope*.

Answer (score 0):

> I would imagine this means that energy is being exchanged actively, so would this energy not become dissonant in some way (heat), perhaps in my ignorance, it seems to me as though there's a sort of violation of thermodynamics taking place.

Indeed, energy is being exchanged between the parts of the disk that are speeding up and the parts that are slowing down. The word “actively” is not meaningful here, but energy exchange does occur.

This is not a violation of thermodynamics. The entropy of the disk is constant. The second law of thermodynamics is $dS\ge 0$, so a constant entropy is perfectly in keeping with thermodynamics.